# Aligning objects

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm writing my first formal specification document and I'm having trouble trying to align text to the left and a tabular table on the right.

Thanks.

```
    \begin{flushleft}

     A patient population includes an initially-empty set of patients(as identified as by their unique set as type $\mathbb{P})$. Each patient has some information about them of type $\mathbb{I})$ 
     \end{flushleft}


     \begin{flushright}
     \begin{tabular}{|l| c |r|}
     test\\
     \hline
     this is a test and this\\is a new line\\

     \end{tabular}
     \end{flushright}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Sounds like a job for `wrapfig` or (more simply, but less nice) `minipage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution, but it should *probably* done with `wrapfig` or similar (depending on your actual use case).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\linewidth}
 A patient population includes an initially-empty set of patients
 (as identified as by their unique set as type $P$).
 Each patient has some information about them of type $I$) 
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l| c |r|}
 test\\
 \hline
 this is a test and this\\is a new line\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @EightSquared :) See edit for better alignment.